# How to split a string based on {} in Java

Tags: java, regex, format

I have a string like this:

`"[{1000, 500, 1}, {1001, 501, 1}, {1002, 501, 2}]"`

(It's not only numbers, could be characters.)

How can I split it into three parts:
`{1000, 500, 1}`
`{1001, 501, 1}`
`{1002, 501, 2}`

2nd step:
Split each new substring into its own fields, e.g. `{1000, 500, 1}`, into `1000`, `500` `1`.

Things I've tried:

1. I've searched online and tried to use Regex and Pattern and Matcher, but none worked out.
2. I've tried to split them based on `,`, but apparently, it's not very properly formatted, there's space in between. Looks like there's some pre-formatting needed?

Any ideas please?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: If the contents are only numbers you could replace space (" ") with no space (""), then split on comma, strip off the first character ("[") from the first entry in the array and the last character from the last entry in the array ("]"), then split each entry again on comma.  That is pretty convoluted though.

Comment: It's a string, thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex: `{\\{[0-9, ]+\\}`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string = "[{1000, 500, 1}, {1001, 501, 1}, {1002, 501, 2}]";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\{[0-9, ]+\\}").matcher(string);
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```

prints:

```
{1000, 500, 1}
{1001, 501, 1}
{1002, 501, 2}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But my string could consist of characters too, so I could modify your regex to be ``Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\{[0-9a-zA-Z, ]+\\}").matcher(string);``, right?